# Laravel problem with passing variables from controller to view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am working on a laravel project and having a problem passing variables from the controller to the view:

this is the controller method:

```
public function index($id){
        $data = [];
        $company = DB::table('companies')->where('id',$id)->first();
        return view('searchResultAdmin.index',  ['company'=>$company, 'Data'=>$data]);
    }
```

and this is the view :

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/SearchResultAdmin',  'method' => 'post')) }}
                            <div class="radio-buttons display-inline">
                                <fieldset class="display-inline group1">
                                    <label class="radio-inline">
                                        <input type="radio" name="SearchLocation" id="value1" value="Actuals" checked>Actuals
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="radio-inline">
                                        <input type="radio" name="SearchLocation" id="value2" value="Forecasts">Forecasts
                                    </label>
                                </fieldset>
                                {{ Form::hidden('id', ($company->id)) }}
                                <fieldset class="display-inline">
                                    <label class="radio-inline">
                                        <input type="radio" name="Order" id="value3" value="Ascending" checked>Ascending
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="radio-inline">
                                        <input type="radio" name="Order" id="value4" value="Descending">Descending
                                    </label>
                                </fieldset>
                            </div>
                            <div class="dropdown-header-table display-inline">
                                <h5>Search By:
                                    <select name="SearchBy">
                                        <option value="Account">Account</option>
                                        <option value="Name">Name</option>
                                        <option value="Year">Year</option>
                                        <option value="Description">Description</option>
                                        <option value="Amount">Amount</option>
                                    </select>
                                </h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="search-input display-inline">
                                <div class="table-form-header">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SearchInputs" placeholder="Search...">
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                                            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        {{ Form::close() }}
```

the error says: undefined variable company on view

Comment: It looks fine, I'd make sure this is the actual controller and view you're hitting.

Comment: i have tested it several times and the data actually comes to view but the hidden input has a problem that i don't know what it is

Comment: The code you've provided wouldn't be reproducible so I'm assuming there's something relevant that isn't included here.  Hook up a debugger and see where $company loses its value

Comment: MIght be because of the brackets inside hidden tag `{{ Form::hidden('id', ($company->id)) }}` try doing `{{ Form::hidden('id', $company->id) }}`

Comment: Look here for more info https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error because of

```
{{ Form::hidden('id', ($company->id)) }}
```

Add `dd($company)` or `dd($company->id)` in your controller before the returning the view and see what you get.

Good luck!

Comment: it actually returns the company object and that confuses me

Comment: Ok, what returns dd($company->id)?

Comment: Are u sure that this is the proper view? searchResultAdmin.index?

Comment: what returns dd($company->id)?

Comment: and it returns the id of the obejct

Comment: I replicated your code and it's working fine. Please check your route is pointing to the correct `controller@method`